# nested click event does not work as required

Tags: javascript

The simplified HTML code below includes 2 nested click events (href and input). When the user clicks on the input field the javascript function SelectTable() linked to href is also triggered, which is not the purpose. How to avoid this?

Thank you for your help in advance.

The code:

```
<a href="javascript:SelectTable();">
<table  id="tableproduct1" class="notselectedElement">
     <tr> 
        <td> Number of elements: <input type="text" name="nrofelements"> </td> 
     </tr>
</table>
</a>
```

Comment: This is not how you should add an event listener. See [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) or use the _onclick_ property / attribute

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't have a table as a child of an anchor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do this using `eventListener`.

I can give you a sample, based on the code you posted.

```
var aTag = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
aTag .addEventListener("click", aTagFn, false);
var iTag = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
iTag.addEventListener("click", inputTagFn, false);
```

---

**Update:**

I've created a similar [**jsfiddle1**](http://jsfiddle.net/hfpCY/1/),  the problem you face,

Using a simple bool variable I have created a workaround.

```
isclicked = true;

function a() {
    if (isclicked) {
        alert("a tag is clicked");
    }
    isclicked = true;
}

function b() {
    alert("input tag is clicked");
    isclicked = false;
}
```

Check this [**JSFiddle2**](http://jsfiddle.net/hfpCY/)

Comment: thnx for all you input(!) ps @user1671639: the javacode in your link http://jsfiddle.net/hfpCY/1/ is not the same as on this site. Question: if I have more tables as in the code (with more 'a's and 'inputs') I still need one bool variable 'isclicked', correct?

Comment: @user2543182  You're correct only if it is a same function for all links and input.  else you need to have multiple isclicked similar to my example.

Comment: it worked (with multiple tables, functions and isclicked vars), thnx! I choose this workaround because of its simplicity.

Comment: @user2543182 I'm glad I was able to help :)